# For $x,y\ge 2$ does $x^4+x^2y^2+y^4$ ever divide $x^4y^4+x^2y^2+1$?

Tags: nt.number-theory

For a problem in combinatorics, it comes down to knowing whether there exist integers $x,y\ge 2$ such that 
$$ 
x^4+x^2y^2+y^4\mid x^4y^4+x^2y^2+1.
$$
Note that $x^6(x^2-y^2)(x^4+x^2y^2+y^4)+(x^2y^2-1)(x^4y^4+x^2y^2+1)=x^{12}-1$ and so we can look at a perhaps simpler problem: Are the only solutions to 
$$ 
x^4+x^2y^2+y^4\mid x^{12}-1
$$
(where $x,y\ge 2$) given by $(x,y)=(5,6)$ and $(x,y)=(6,5)$?

Comment: It may or may not be useful to notice that $$x^4+x^2y^2+y^4=(x^2+xy+y^2)(x^2-xy+y^2)$$ and $$x^4y^4+x^2y^2+1=(x^2y^2+xy+1)(x^2y^2-xy+1)$$

Comment: You wonder if we ever have that (1) $u^2+uv+v^2$ divides $u^2v^2+uv+1$ with the added requirement (2) that $u,v$ are perfect squares.  Without this final requirement it happens rarely, but sometimes ($13$ times for $v \lt u \le 10000$). Perhaps figuring out when (1) happens would be a good start.

Comment: Suppose one considers specific instances for x, e.g. 2401 + 49y^2 + y^4 divides (or not) 2401y^4 + 49y^2 +1.  Can one come up with nice conditions on y to predict when this happens?  Can such conditions be "uniformized" over families of x?  Gerhard "Likes Solving By Plugging In" Paseman, 2014.07.19

Comment: Taking that particular example, one gets that the desired divisibility implies -2400(49y^2+2402) is divisible by the "smaller" quartic.  Since the factor is odd, this reduces to 3*5^2(49y^2+2402), which quickly limits the size of feasible y.  Perhaps one can show quickly this way that x cannot be small.  Gerhard "For All But Infinitely Many" Paseman, 2014.07.19

Answer (score 7):

It seems to me that you need both $$p=x^2+xy+y^2$$ and $$q=x^2-xy+y^2$$ to divide $$r=x^4y^4+x^2y^2+1$$ Considering all expressions as polynomials in $x$, the remainder when you divide $r$ by $p$ is $$(y^7-y^3)x-y^4+1$$ and the remainder when you divide $r$ by $q$ is  $$(y^3-y^7)x-y^4+1$$ if Maple and I are on the same page. These remainders are both zero if and only if $y=\pm1$.

Comment: The $x$-polynomial remainders need not be zero for $p\mid r$ and $q\mid r$ to hold (for a given $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$).

Comment: @Myerson It is important to distinguish integers and indeterminants.
Let $x$ and $y$ be integers greater than 1, and
let $X$ and $Y$ be indeterminants. Consider
$f(X,Y), g(X,Y)\in\mathbb{Q}(Y)[X]$. Certainly $f(X,Y)\equiv 0\pmod {g(X,Y)}$
implies $f(x,y)\equiv 0\pmod {g(x,y)}$ for all integers $x,y>1$, but the
converse is false.
For example, $(X^2+2)\pmod {XY}$ is nonzero, but $(2^2+2)\pmod {2\cdot3}$ is
zero. For this reason, I do not see that Gerry has solved the problem.

Comment: You have reduced the problem to showing that "the integers $(y^7-y^3)x-y^4+1$ and $(y^3-y^7)x-y^4+1$ do not divide $x^4y^4+x^2y^2+1$ (for all $x,y\ge 2$)".

Comment: I accept the objections. I note (for whatever it might be worth) that $(y^7-y^3)x-y^4+1=(y^4-1)(xy^3-1)$

Comment: @JohnBamberg: I don't think so. Instead, we have reduced the problem to showing that we cannot have that, simultaneously, $(y^7-y^3)x-y^4+1$ is divisible by $x^2+xy+y^2$ and $(y^3-y^7)x-y^4+1$ is divisible by $x^2-xy+y^2$ (for any $x,y\geq 2$).

Comment: Note that $x, y$ must be relatively prime in order for $x^4 + x^2 y^2 + y^4$ to divide $x^4 y^4 + x^2 y^2 + 1$; I claim that $p = x^2 + xy + y^2$ and $q = x^2 - xy + y^2$ are also relatively prime. Assume not; then the common divisor also divides $2p - q = (x + y)^2$ and $2q - p = (x - y)^2$; we would therefore also get a common divisor of $x + y, x - y$. As the relevant common divisor can't be 2 (by checking parity), we would have a common divisor of $x, y$, which is impossible. Therefore $p, q$ are relatively prime.

It's therefore sufficient to show that $p|r, q|r$ to have that $pq|r$.

Comment: @user44191: It is trivial that it is sufficient to show that $p\mid r$ and $q\mid r$ cannot hold simultaneously (because $pq\mid r$ implies $p\mid r$ and $q\mid r$). What you really observed is the fact that the reduced statement is no stronger than the original one (i.e. the impossibility of $pq\mid r$).

Comment: @GHfromMO Blah, of course. My apologies; I'm tired.

Comment: @GHfromMO: Ah yes, thanks for that.

Comment: One idea I've add is to use Zsigmondy's Theorem. There exists a primitive prime divisor $p$ dividing $x^6-y^6=(x^2-y^2)(x^4+x^2y^2+y^4)$ and so $p$ divides $x^6-1$ or $x^6+1$ (as we also know that $p\ne 2$). Still no idea what to do with this yet.

Comment: Of course $pq \mid r$ implies $pq \mid r-pq=(x^4-1)(y^4-1)$ which factors quite a bit further. Not that it is clear if that helps.

Answer (score 6):

I do not know whether there is any advantage to considering this problem in the ring of Eisenstein integers $\mathbb{Z}[\omega],$ where $\omega = e ^{\frac{2 \pi i}{3}},$ which is a PID. Then we have  to ask when we can have $(x - \omega y)(x +\omega y)(x - \omega^{2}y )(x+\omega^{2}y)$ dividing $(xy- \omega)(xy +\omega)(xy- \omega^{2})(xy +\omega^{2})$ in $\mathbb{Z}[\omega],$ where $x,y$ are rational integers. I have not been able to pursue this to provide further insight myself, but someone else might.

Later remark: It is easy to check that the power of $1-\omega$ dividing both expressions is the same: it is $0$ if $3$ divides $xy,$ and $2$ if $3$ does not divided $xy.$ Hence we can omit the prime  $1-\omega$ from our considerations, and we only need to worry about primes in $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$ such that $N(\pi)$ is a rational prime congruent to $1$ (mod $3$). If $\pi$ is such a prime dividing the leftmost product, we note that $\pi$ divides exactly one of the terms in the rightmost product (and, in fact, $\pi$ also divides exactly one term in the leftmost product). This leads (if the required divisibility holds ) relatively easily to the observation (already made by the OP) that the leftmost expression divides $y^{12}-1$ (and/or $x^{12}-1,$ there is symmetry in $x$ and $y$), but it is unclear to me at present whether this viewpoint provides any more useful information.

Later edit: I noticed that Aaron Meyerowitz's observation (in a comment after Gerry Myerson's answer) that  if the required divisibility holds, then $x^{4} + x^{2}y^{2} +y^{4}$ divides $(x^{4}-1)(y^{4}-1)$ can be derived this way. That is not particularly surprising, and the direct derivation is easier. However, perhaps less obvious is that we also have that $x^{4} + x^{2}y^{2} +y^{4}$ divides $(y^{8}+y^{4}+1)(x^{8}+x^{4}+1)$. While 
$(x^{4} + x^{2}y^{2} +y^{4})^{2}$divides $(x^{12}-1)(y^{12}-1),$ it is not immediately obvious to me that this last claimed divisibility is a consequence of that- for example, there might a priori be a prime $\pi$ such that $x^{4}-1$ is divisible by some higher than expected power of $\pi$- so I outline a proof:

Note that if $\pi$ is a prime in $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$ with $N(\pi) \equiv 1$ (mod $3$), then if $\pi^{m}$ divides both $x^{4}-1$ and $x^{2}- \omega y^{2},$ we have $\pi^{m}$ divides $\omega^{2}y^{4}-1,$ so that $\pi^{m}$ divides $y^{4}-\omega^{4}.$ It follows that $N(\pi)^{m}$ divides $y^{8}+y^{4} + 1.$  Hence it follows that (in $\mathbb{Z}$), ${\rm gcd}(x^{4}-1,x^{4} + x^{2}y^{2} + y^{4})$ divides $y^{8}+y^{4}+1$ (as before, the power of $3$ is taken care of). Similarly ${\rm gcd}(y^{4}-1,x^{4} + x^{2}y^{2} + y^{4})$ divides $x^{8}+x^{4}+1$. Since $x^{4}+ x^{2}y^{2} + y^{4}$ divides $(x^{4}-1)(y^{4}-1),$ the claim is established (note that ${\rm gcd}(x^{4}-1,y^{4}-1)$ has the form $2^{a}3^{b}$ if the original divisibility holds (and $(x^{2}-1)(y^{2}-1) \neq 0$).

We can continue this analysis: we see (if the original divisibilty holds) that $x^{4}+x^{2}y^{2}+y^{4}$ divides 
${\rm gcd}(y^{2}-1,\frac{x^{6}-1}{x^{2}-1}){\rm gcd}(y^{2}+1,\frac{x^{6}+1}{x^{2}+1})
{\rm gcd}(x^{2}-1,\frac{y^{6}-1}{y^{2}-1}){\rm gcd}(x^{2}+1,\frac{y^{6}+1}{y^{2}+1}).$

Additional edit: Conversely, it is easy to check that the rightmost product divides $3(x^{4}+y^{4}+ x^{2}y^{2})$ given that $x$ and $y$ are coprime. Also, the righmost product divides $3(x^{4}y^{4}+x^{2}y^{2}+1).$

It follows that $x^{4} + y^{4} + y^{2}x^{2}$ divides $x^{4}y^{4}+y^{2}x^{2}+1$ if and only if ${\rm gcd}(x,y) = 1$ and $x^{4}+x^{2}y^{2}+y^{4}$ is equal to
${\rm gcd}(y^{2}-1,\frac{x^{6}-1}{x^{2}-1}){\rm gcd}(y^{2}+1,\frac{x^{6}+1}{x^{2}+1})
{\rm gcd}(x^{2}-1,\frac{y^{6}-1}{y^{2}-1}){\rm gcd}(x^{2}+1,\frac{y^{6}+1}{y^{2}+1})$
when  $xy$ is divisible by $3$ or $3(x^{4}+x^{2}y^{2}+y^{4})$ is equal to 
${\rm gcd}(y^{2}-1,\frac{x^{6}-1}{x^{2}-1}){\rm gcd}(y^{2}+1,\frac{x^{6}+1}{x^{2}+1})
{\rm gcd}(x^{2}-1,\frac{y^{6}-1}{y^{2}-1}){\rm gcd}(x^{2}+1,\frac{y^{6}+1}{y^{2}+1})$
when $xy$ is not divisible by $3$.

Comment: And then (for whatever it is worth) the first thing is  $\gcd(y^2-1,x^4+x^2+1)=\gcd((y-1)(y+1),(x^2+x+1)(x^2-x+1))$ which is the product of four things $\gcd(y \pm 1,x^2 \pm x +1)$ (since the two things on the right are odd and coprime while the two things on the right can share at most a factor of $2$.) Similarly for the third factor.  Over $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ one could do something similar for the second and fourth.

Comment: @AaronMyerowitz: Yes, that is correct, there are several ways to refine things further, either over $\mathbb{Z},$ or $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$, or $\mathbb{Z}[i],$ though I had not tried the last one.

Comment: A similar thing to observe is that if we ask what the solution to the quartic
$$
x^4 y^4 + x^2 y^2 + 1 - k (x^4 + x^2 y^2 + y^4) = 0
$$
is in terms of $x$ (over the reals), we find that the four solutions (except when $k=y^4$) are
$$
x=\pm \sqrt{  \frac{(k-1)y^2 \pm \sqrt{4k-(3+2k+3k^2)y^4+4ky^8}}{2(k-y^4)}}.
$$
So then we ask when $k-\frac{3+2k+3k^2}{4}z^4+k z^8$ is a perfect square (where $k,z\in \mathbb{Z}^+$), and it seems (by computer) the answer is "if and only if $k=1$".

Comment: @John: does that computer search use Baker's theorem to bound $k$? Or something clever with numbers of the form $a^2+ab+b^2$?

Comment: @ZackWolske: nothing clever, just brute force. We know that $k$ needs to be odd, and substituting $k=2n+1$ gives us $-3n^2z^4+(2n+1)(z^4-1)^2$.

Comment: If you have a complete proof ((by computer or not) that the divisibility is impossible when neither of $x,y$ is $1,$ , then you should give it as an answer.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson: no proof at all yet. A few times I thought I had it but there's always been a gaping hole. What I claimed above is false. Take $k=81$ and $z=6$. However, it yields an irrational when plugged into the formula for $x$. The best lead we have at the moment is Geoff's equation with the product of the four gcd's.