# How large can the gcd of a pair of two-variable polynomials be?

Tags: nt.number-theory

This question is inspired by [For $x,y\ge 2$ does $x^4+x^2y^2+y^4$ ever divide $x^4y^4+x^2y^2+1$?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/176351/2363).

> Let $f(x,y), g(x,y)\in \mathbb{Z}[x,y]$ with no common factor, such that every intersection point between the curves $f(x,y) = 0$ and $g(x,y) = 0$ has multiplicity one. Can we show that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is a nonempty Zariski open subset $U_\epsilon$ and a constant $c_\epsilon$ such that for any integer point $(x,y)\in U_\epsilon(\mathbb{Z})$ we have $\gcd(f(x,y),g(x,y)) \le c_\epsilon \max(|x|,|y|)^{2+\epsilon}$?

A closely related question is

> Let $S\subseteq \mathbb{Z}^2$ be a finite set of integer points. Can we show that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is a nonempty Zariski open subset $U_\epsilon$ and a constant $c_\epsilon$ such that for any integer point $(x,y)\in U_\epsilon(\mathbb{Z})$ we have $\prod_{(a,b)\in S}\gcd(x-a,y-b) \le c_\epsilon \max(|x|,|y|)^{2+\epsilon}$?

The two questions are equivalent if the intersection of the curves $f(x,y) = 0, g(x,y) = 0$ is exactly the set of points $S$. I'll focus on the second question since it feels more intuitive to me.

Since these questions are likely to be hard, it would also be interesting to know if either is implied by a well-known conjecture.

> Can we at least say anything about the special case $f(x,y) = x^3-x, g(x,y) = y^3-y$?

In this special case, there is a set of eight bad lines on which the gcd grows like $\max(|x|,|y|)^3$ and a set of eight bad hyperbolas on which the gcd grows like $\max(|x|,|y|)^{\frac{5}{2}}$. Aside from these bad cases, the worst point $(x,y)$ with $1 < x < y \le 500000$ that came up in a computer search was $(x,y) = (76941, 319301)$, with $\gcd(x^3-x,y^3-y) = 26793198284040 < 319301^{2.44}$.

### Heuristic Argument

Suppose we try to construct a bad point $(x,y)$ as follows. Start by picking a collection of prime powers $p_i^{e_i}$ whose product will be $\prod_{(a,b)\in S}\gcd(x-a,y-b)$. Next, for each prime power, we choose one of the $|S|$ points to be congruent to $x,y$ modulo $p_i^{e_i}$. Finally, we solve for $x,y$ using the Chinese Remainder Theorem, and hope that $|x|,|y| \le \prod_i p_i^{\frac{e_i}{2+\epsilon}}$. If there are no algebraic conspiracies, we expect the total number of successes of this procedure to be something like

$$\prod_{p} \left(1+\sum_{e>0}\frac{|S|p^{\frac{2e}{2+\epsilon}}}{p^{2e}}\right) \approx \zeta\left(2-\frac{2}{2+\epsilon}\right)^{|S|} < \infty.$$

### Actual Arguments

We can prove right away that the exponent $2$ can't possibly be improved if $S$ contains a set of four points, no three of which are collinear. Let $P_i = (a_i,b_i), i = 1, ..., 4$ be four such points in $S$, and let $Q = (c,d)$ be any integer point such that the conic passing through $P_1,P_2,P_3,P_4,Q$ is a hyperbola (any nonempty Zariski open set contains infinitely many such $Q$). By the theory of Pell equations, there are infinitely many integer points $(x,y)$ on this hyperbola. For such points, we can show (easy exercise) that up to constant factors we have

$$\gcd(x-a_i,y-b_i) \sim \max(|x|,|y|)^{\frac{1}{2}},$$

so the product of those four gcds grows like $\max(|x|,|y|)^2$.

We can also prove that the optimal exponent is, if not $2+\epsilon$, certainly at most $\sqrt{|S|}+\epsilon$. The main point is that if $p(x,y)$ is a nonzero polynomial and $k$ is an integer such that for each $(a,b) \in S$ the polynomial $p(x,y)$ is contained in the ideal $(x-a,y-b)^k$ (i.e., the point $(a,b)$ lies on the curve defined by $p(x,y) = 0$ with multiplicity at least $k$), then for any integer point $(x,y)$ we have

$$\gcd(x-a,y-b)^k = \gcd((x-a)^k,(y-b)^k,p(x,y)) \mid p(x,y),$$

so if $p$ has degree $d$ and $p(x,y) \ne 0$ then

$$\prod_{(a,b)\in S}\gcd(x-a,y-b) \ll |p(x,y)|^{\frac{1}{k}} \ll \max(|x|,|y|)^{\frac{d}{k}}.$$

In order to find such a polynomial $p$ of degree $d$, we need to solve a system of $|S|\frac{k(k+1)}{2}$ homogeneous linear equations in $\frac{(d+1)(d+2)}{2}$ variables, and we can do this if $d$ is large and $\frac{d}{k} \ge \sqrt{|S|}+\epsilon$.

Comment: Just a minor remark: If you restrict $x,y$ to be powers of $2$ (or to have prime factors only from a given finite set), Schmidt's Subspace theorem yields this even with exponent $\epsilon$.

Comment: (And this remark concerns both variants of the question.) How is question 1 implies by question 2 (assuming $\{f = g = 0\} \subset \mathbb{Z}^2$)? Aren't you assuming $f$ and $g$ univariate (or homogeneous) for this implication?

Comment: Also your first question has to be revised. (What happens to the statement when you replace $f,g$ by $f^m,g^m$?) Perhaps you want to assume that $f,g$ are irreducible?

Comment: yeah, I just noticed that (and edited to fix it). Another bad case with the old version would come up if f, g were both products of many homogeneous linear polynomials.

Comment: In my first remark I was assuming $f,g$ have non-zero constant terms (resp. $(0,0) \notin S$); if $(0,0)$ is a simple intersection point of $f = 0$ and $g=0$ (resp. $S$ contains $(0,0)$), and when $x,y$ are restricted to be $T$-units, the same remark applies with the exponent $1+\epsilon$. (And by the way, you do not need in your two questions to include the constant $c_{\epsilon}$: it is absorbed by the exponent $2+\epsilon$ while you may always delete from $U_{\epsilon}$ a finite number of exceptional points.)

Comment: This is related to Granville-Langevin conjecture. Check: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/149631/is-there-a-generalization-of-granville-langevin-conjecture-for-number-fields

Comment: @joro: The conjecture you refer to (which incidentally is a vast generalization of Roth's theorem), is actually equivalent to the ABC conjecture; this is due to Langevin after work of Elkies, cf. Theorem 12.2.12 in Bombieri and Gubler's book *Heights in diophantine approximation*. (This also answers your linked question.) But how is this related to zeb's questions?

Comment: @VesselinDimitrov might be wrong, but for homogeneous $f,g$ and coprime $x,y$, if the gcd is large enough (which the question asks) then $F(x,y)=f(x,y)g(x,y)$ will have small radical since the gcd will contribute square.

Comment: Indeed, @joro 's remark proves that for the case that $f,g$ are *homogeneous* polynomials with $fg$ splitting into distinct linear factors over $\mathbb{C}$, ABC implies the affirmative answer to zeb's first question, at least if we restrict to co-prime pairs $(m,n)$. E.g. this solves the problem (under ABC) for $f = x^3-xy^2$ and $g = y^3-x^2y$. But I don't see how this could apply to the inhomogeneous case of $f = x^3-x$, $g = y^3-y$.

Comment: @VesselinDimitrov I am pretty sure GL can't be relaxed to drop the  homogeneous condition. Why in a comment zeb appears concerned about "if f, g were both products of many homogeneous linear polynomials."

Comment: @joro: Because GL requires (of course) that $(m,n) = 1$, and zeb does not assume this restriction.

Comment: @VesselinDimitrov I am not sure I understand correctly, but aren't invertible polynomial maps of sufficiently large degree counterexample? This map has polynomial inverse and clearly covers Z^2: $(x,y) \mapsto (x-(x+y)^5,y+(x+y)^5) $ ?

Comment: @VesselinDimitrov Unfortunately I don't get experimental support for the given map. The inverse map is of degree $5$ which makes $x,y$ large :(

Comment: @Indeed... and this adds some further evidence to zeb's statement. I will delete my last comment, and will instead post an answer to formulate a possible inhomogeneous Langevin statement which would include zeb's conjecture alongside Roth's theorem and the ABC conjecture.

Comment: @VesselinDimitrov I suspect if $(f,g)$ is surjective on Z^2 things get complicated IMHO.

Comment: @joro: OK, I do not know if such a conjectural generalization could be formulated. Let me just point out an interesting consequence of the restricted assertion (the one involving $x^3-x$ and $y^3-y$): *For any $\epsilon > 0$, there are only finitely many pairs of distinct positive integers $n \neq m$ such that $(n^3-n)/(m^3-m)$ is a positive integer smaller than $n^{1-\epsilon}$.* This now is a question involving large integral points on elliptic curves.

Comment: @VesselinDimitrov if I choose surjective $(f,g)$ and ask about them this appears formulation to me. Btw, the invertible polynomial maps are automorphisms, so they might not be entirely useless.

Comment: @joro: As you say above, polynomial automorphisms are irrelevant for this problem, since their inverse has the same degree, thereby only producing examples where the exponent is $1$.

Comment: The following related question also seems attractive to me: *Is there an $\epsilon > 0$ such that (a) There are infinitely many pairs of distinct positive integers $n \neq m$ with $\min \Big( \mathrm{GCD}(n-1,m-1), \mathrm{GCD}(n,m) \Big) > \max(n,m)^{\frac{1}{2}+\epsilon}$? (b) The solutions to $\min \Big( \mathrm{GCD}(n-1,m-1), \mathrm{GCD}(n,m), \mathrm{GCD}(n+1,m+1) \Big) > \max(n,m)^{\epsilon}$ are Zariski-dense?*

Comment: @VesselinDimitrov For your question (b), you can take $m = k(n^3-n)+n$ to achieve $\epsilon = \frac{1}{3}.$

Comment: @zeb: Right; then the right question would have the exponent $\frac{1}{3}+\epsilon$.

Comment: Such results follow from Vojta's conjectures, see e.g. this paper of Silverman. http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0407415.pdf

Comment: @FelipeVoloch: I see: it follows from Thm. 2 of that paper under Vojta's conjecture for blow-ups of $\mathbb{P}^2$, with $S = \emptyset$ and $(x_0,x_1,x_2) = (1,x,y)$. This is a very neat simultaneous generalization of zeb's statement and the one I knew to be a consequence of Schmidt's theorem, and also of the homogeneous case with $m, n$ restricted to be co-prime (which is a consequence of ABC as noted by Joro in the comments). I deleted the answer that I just gave.

Comment: In case anyone ever looks at this question again and wants the exact reference, the article that Felipe Voloch refers to is: J.H Silverman, Generalized greatest common divisors, divisibility sequences, and Vojta's conjecture on blowups, *Monatsch. Math.* **145** (2005), 333-350.